# How to show navigationBar (primefaces) on successful login (JSF 2.0)

Tags: jsf-2, authentication, navigation, primefaces, show

I would like to show the navigation bar on successful login in JSF 2.0. Here is a part of my `login.xhtml` file.
The navigation bar is a Primefaces component that you can see [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/notificationBar.jsf).

As you can see, the navigation bar can be shown by triggering the method `topBar.show()`
But how can I trigger it after I get a successful login?

```
  <h:form>
    <p:messages showDetail="false" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
      <h:outputLabel for="pseudo" value="#{i18n.Pseudo}" />
      <h:inputText id="pseudo" label="#{i18n.Pseudo}" required="true" value="#{loginController.grimpeur.login}"
        maxlength="128" />
      <h:outputLabel for="password" value="#{i18n.Password}:" />
      <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{loginController.grimpeur.password}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton type="submit" action="#{loginController.processLogin}" value="#{i18n.Ok}" />
    <h:commandButton type="button" value="#{i18n.Password_forgotten}" onclick="dlg.show();" />
  </h:form>

  <p:notificationBar position="top" effect="slide" widgetVar="loginBar" styleClass="top">
    <h:graphicImage value="#{loginController.grimpeur.login}/#{loginController.grimpeur.avatar}" width="80" height="70"
      title="avatar" />
    <h:outputFormat id="logged_in_msg" value="#{i18n.Welcome_logged_in_user}" style="color:#FFCC00;font-size:36px;">
      <f:param value="#{loginController.grimpeur.login}" />
      <f:param value="#{i18n.Climbing}" />
    </h:outputFormat>
  </p:notificationBar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve it with PrimeFaces v3.0.RC2's [RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/requestContext.jsf). It should be something like this:

```
<p:notificationBar widgetVar="bar">  
    <h:outputText value="You have successfully log in!" />  
</p:notificationBar>

<p:commandButton type="submit" actionListener="#{loginController.processLogin}" 
                 value="#{i18n.Ok}" />

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginController {
   public void processLogin(ActionEvent actionEvent) { 
      boolean successful;
      // process your login here

      if (successful) {
         RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
         context.execute("bar.show();"); 
      }
   }
}
```